# Solution to accuratly determine or set frame rate and callback on new rendered frames locally

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, html5-video

I was curious if anyone knew of a solution for loading and playing a video, and determining the frame rate, or being able to set this frame rate and will accurately tell you when a new frame is rendered. From what I have found the only way to get the current location of the html 5 video player is the current time attribute. This, however only updates around 4-5 times a second for me. I need to update the page every frame. Does anyone know any solutions to this? I was thinking maybe I can locally stream FFMPEG to my electron window however this seems overly complicated. I have seen some of the costly libraries but I have not seen an up-to-date opensource solution to this. Any Ideas?